# How to visualize halide schedule?

Tags: halide

How to visualize halide schedule like [this video](https://youtu.be/3uiEyEKji0M?t=413)? 
HalideTraceViz with [viz.sh](https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/auto_scheduler/apps/camera_pipe/viz.sh) in halide repository seems to visualize that.
But camera_pipe.avi generated by [viz.sh](https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/auto_scheduler/apps/camera_pipe/viz.sh) just shows nothing but black about 10 seconds. This is the log while playing the .avi file with mplayer.

```
$ mplayer bin/camera_pipe.avi 
MPlayer 1.1-4.8 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing bin/camera_pipe.avi.
libavformat version 54.20.4 (external)
Mismatching header version 54.20.3
AVI file format detected.
[aviheader] Video stream found, -vid 0
AVI: No audio stream found -> no sound.
VIDEO:  [H264]  1920x1080  24bpp  25.000 fps   15.0 kbps ( 1.8 kbyte/s)
Clip info:
 Software: Lavf54.20.4
Load subtitles in bin/
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 54.35.0 (external)
Selected video codec: [ffh264] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg H.264)
==========================================================================
Audio: no sound
Starting playback...
Unsupported AVPixelFormat 53
Movie-Aspect is undefined - no prescaling applied.
VO: [vdpau] 1920x1080 => 1920x1080 Planar YV12 
V:  10.0 250/250  5%  4%  0.0% 0 0 


Exiting... (End of file)
```

Comment: Also see `halide_set_custom_trace()`, `Halide::Func::set_custom_trace()` and `Halide::Pipeline::set_custom_trace()`. You could graphically represent trace events in real time and/or record them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That viz script is just stale and buggy. I'll fix it. Try the ones in local_laplacian and bilateral_grid.

Unfortunately the visualizer is super user-unfriendly right now. Perhaps it should take json or something as the input instead of just positional command-line arguments.